# NSMainBundle and iCloud

Tags: ios

My app was rejected by Apple for the following reason:
We still found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines.

In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your app stores 3.46 MB. To check how much data your app is storing.

Thank you for your reply. However, only content that the user creates using your app, should be backed up by iCloud.

However the files that Apple is talking about are .HTML files and CSS file that are included in the bundle of the application. This is offline data HTML files that need to be viewed offline for users of the application (manual files) and are being loaded in like this:

```
htmlString = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[rssData objectForKey:@"content"] ofType:@"html"]];
```

And this HTML string will be loaded to a UIWebView.

How can i keep the same structure but make it acceptable for Apple AppStore?

Comment: Are you storing anything into the `NSDocumentDirectory`?

Comment: No no storing of these files in NSDocumentDirectory.. Their are just in the bundle of the application and being loaded from NSBundle mainBundle.

Comment: Do you copy any files anywhere at all when starting the app the first time?

Comment: No not at all.. Just get an local JSON feed from NSMainBundle and show rows in a TableView. When you press a row a HTML string is being loaded to the webview. The names of the HTML files are in the JSON feed.